# Combining textContent into one header when rendering Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Very new to javascript here, just two days in, but I have decided to start a pretty ambitious project using Javascript and Firebase.

Below I am trying to render the Javascript from Firestore to HTML, but as you can probably see, it's creating 4 H5's. Ideally, I have all the text inside of one H5, but formatted nicely.

Here is my javascript (again I just started learning this two days ago so I am very new)

```
const resultList = document.querySelector('#horseList') 

function renderResult(doc){
    let li = document.createElement('li');

    var resultDiv = document.createElement('div');
    resultDiv.className = ('result');

    var resultImage = document.createElement('div');
    resultImage.className = ('data-image');

    var resultFooter = document.createElement('div');
    resultFooter.className = ('result-footer');

    var resultText = document.createElement('div');
    resultText.className = ('results-text');

    var resultButton = document.createElement('button');
    resultButton.className = ('button tiny w-button');
    resultButton.innerHTML = "View";

    let name = document.createElement ('h5');
    name.className = ('data-text');
    let age = document.createElement ('h5');
    age.className = ('data-text');
    let type = document.createElement ('h5');
    type.className = ('data-text');
    let price = document.createElement ('h5');
    price.className = ('data-text');

    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    name.textContent = doc.data().name;
    age.textContent = doc.data().age;
    type.textContent = doc.data().type;
    price.textContent = doc.data().price;

    resultList.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(resultDiv);
            resultDiv.appendChild(resultImage);
            resultDiv.appendChild(resultFooter);
                resultFooter.appendChild(resultText);
                resultFooter.appendChild(resultButton);
                    resultText.appendChild(name);
                    resultText.appendChild(type);
                    resultText.appendChild(age);
                    resultText.appendChild(price);
}

//connect to database & get data
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("Horses").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {

    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        renderResult(doc);
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

And here is what I am hoping to achieve in HTML

```
<ul id="horseList" role="list" class="result-list">
    <li>
      <div class="result">
        <div class="data-image"></div>
        <div class="result-footer">
          <div class="results-text">
            <h5 class="data-text">Taffy, 8 | Arabian</h5>
            <h5 class="data-text">$12,000</h5>
          </div><a href="imagelinkhere" target="_blank" class="button tiny w-button">View</a></div>
```

Updated code:

```
        let lineone = document.createElement ('h5');
    lineone.className = ('data-text');
    let linetwo = document.createElement ('h5');
    linetwo.className = ('data-text');


    li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    lineone.textContent = ${doc.data().name}, ${doc.data().age}, ${doc.data().type}; 
    linetwo.textContent = ${doc.data().price};
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Heya Bailey, welcome to SO! I assume you are getting 5 h5s and just want to make them into 2? For that you could set the text content of those as something like `${doc.data().name}, ${doc.data().age} | ${doc.data().type}`

Comment: Thanks @frunkad, I get where you're going with that, but honestly, I am kind of lost as to where those would go. Check the edited question for updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all the data calls into a single string variable using template literals, and then set that variable to the text content of your h5 element:

```
const string = `${doc.data().name}, ${doc.data().age} | ${doc.data().type}`;

let h5 = document.createElement('h5');

h5.textContent = string;
```

Comment: This is great, but it seems I am getting a type error. It says doc.data(...).type is not a function.

Comment: I originally had 'doc.data().type()' which was a typo mistake, and edited it to 'doc.data().type'; are you using the later?

Comment: Aha that was it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

how are you? you can try to use the template literals, creating just one h5 for the 3 attributes name, age, type:
phrase.textContent = `${doc.data().name}, ${doc.data().age} ${doc.data().type}`

Comment: Would the final result look like this? const string = `${doc.data().name}, ${doc.data().age} | ${doc.data().type()}`;

Comment: Yes, just a detail, the template literals are recorded by grave accumulations (``), it is used a lot for concatenation, then leaves its shape in this way $ {expression} and join with your text for example: `Hello world $ {doc.data (). name} `